# VBA: Calculating LN Daily Returns - Subscript out of Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to arrays in VBA, this is much easier in MatLab, but I can't seem to get the code to work. Simply, I am calculating the LN daily returns of an index: LN(t0 / t1) Here is the code:

```
Dim Index() As Variant

Dim Ret() As Variant

    Index = Range("B9:B29")

    For i = 1 To UBound(Index) - 1

        Ret(i, 1) = Log(Index(i, 1) / Index(i + 1, 1))

    Next i
```

I get an error in the Ret(i,1) loop. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have to `ReDim Ret(1 to UBound(Index) - 1, 1 to 1)` before you add any values to it.

Comment: Thanks! I now get an overflow error at the same line [Ret(i,1) = Log(index....)

Answer (score 0):

Found it, when ReDim it turns Return into single dimension array. So Ret(i,1) should be Ret(1). I wonder why Index = Range returns 2 dimensional array?

```
Dim Index() As Variant
    Dim Ret() As Variant


    Index = Range("B9:B29")

    ReDim Ret(1 To UBound(Index) - 1)


    'Debug.Print Index(1, 1)


    For i = 1 To UBound(Index) - 1

        Ret(i) = Log(Index(i, 1) / Index((i + 1), 1))

    Next i
```

Comment: `someRange.Value` always returns a 2D array, unless `someRange` is a single cell, in which case it just returns the value of that cell.